# How can I apply kotlin compiler 2(Plus, if can gradle 1.8.+)?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I've heard that kotlin compiler 2 is faster than the old one.
And also from Gradle 1.8.+. The build speed is much improved.

So, At the moment, I use

`org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10`

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0`

And also I found this document(https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew19.html#try-the-k2-compiler-in-your-project). But this doesn't explain clearly where I should add the `kotlin.experimental.tryK2=true`.

And then, I found an answer from GPT. And added this line to the build.gradle(project level) at the end.

```
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xallow-kotlin-package", "-P", "kotlin.experimental.tryK2=true")
    }
}
```

It is buildable. However, whether I comment(or remove) the line or not. The build speed is around 10 seconds. Not so difference.

How can I improve the build speed? I've heard gradle 1.8.x and compiler 2 can't put together at the moment. If there's a solution to make the build faster could you please share the idea?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `kotlin.experimental.tryK2=true` to the `gradle.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to 
`Settings`->`Build, Execution`, `Deployment`->`Build Tools`->`Gradle` 
and Choose `download jdk` from the bottom of `jdk list`.<

You can download `openjdk 20` which will probably be better for you.